# Cloud Functions: Functions finished with 'load error'

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have a http triggered cloud function that is throwing this error, albeit very rarely. This error is particularly difficult to replicate.

[image]

I have searched around Stack Overflow but yielded no results. I have also attempted to trigger it manually from the Google Cloud console and it all works fine.

Would anyone be able to advice what does this error point to?

EDIT: Fully expanded log
[image]

Comment: Without seeing an MCVE, there's not likely much to say.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If we examine the complete, un-filtered log entries in Stackdriver, are there any other clues?

Comment: @DougStevenson I am trying my best to produce a MCVE but honestly I can't even tell which areas would have led to such errors. Manual triggers on cloud console and on browser works fine. Examining the stackdriver logs also doesn't reveal much. Would you be able to advice what are the possible causes of 'load error' at least?

Comment: The error might be more complicated that it seems at a first glance. I highly recommend you to open a public issue tracker with Google Cloud Platform Support. I attached you [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491477&template=1161411) the form to fill up. I hope it helps.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue.